ProxyBillingActivity means in firebase analytic
Hi I have implemented the Google Play Billing Library and my app has firebase integrated as well.
In the firebase console, on the "Views by Page title and screen class" section, I find ProxyBillingActivity.
I wonder, what does it mean?
is it the event of user initiated the purchase dialog?


ProxyBillingActivity is an activity that acts as an intermediary or a "proxy" between the app and the google play store. also it handling the purchase flow as part of the billing process. plus it is  responsible for presenting the user interface to make purchases and handling the communication with google pay billing services.
